# Why can't I add contents in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

When I use Sphinx to document my program, I can't add content. It just raises this exception:

```
invalid option block.
```

Here's my markup:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   code
   requirment
```

what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it does not look tile a comment problem. Try to put a blank line in this piece of code to look like this:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   code
   requirment
```

Comment: Thank you very much:D I add '.rst' behind it then it works correctly.